# Долгое преобразование данных из MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

Начал изучать C#.
Проблема вот в чем. Подключаюсь базе используя стандартный коннектор, получаю данные. Но вот преобразование этих данных происходит очень медленно.
Количество строк 50000 - 150000, по времени преобразование занимает 30-60 сек.
Хотя сам запрос и получение данных из БД происходит менее чем за 1 сек.

Возможно ли как-то ускорить этот процесс???

Причем на отладчике видно что в это время происходит очень частая сборка мусора подозреваю что в этом причина. Класс Price имеет три свойства.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код следующий:

```
List<Price> Prices = new List<Price>();


                Db_Connection.Open();
                MySqlDataReader myReader = commandDatabase.ExecuteReader();

                if (myReader.HasRows)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        Prices.Add(new Price());
                        Prices[i].Timestamp = Convert.ToInt32(ConvertToUnixTimestamp(myReader.GetString(1)));
                        Prices[i].Bid = Convert.ToDouble(myReader.GetString(2));
                        Prices[i].Ask = Convert.ToDouble(myReader.GetString(3));
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                Db_Connection.Close();
```

Comment: Попробуйте сделать предварительный размер коллекции побольше, можно 10 000 элементов. Подавайте данные в конструктор класса, а то вы тратите время впустую, извлекая элемент из коллекции (причём несколько раз) и присваивая значения свойств. В ваших преобразованиях не видно ничего сверх сложного, вы уверены что время тратится именно на них?

Comment: >>Хотя сам запрос и получение данных из БД происходит менее чем за 1 сек<< Как вы это проверяли? Делали пустой Read()? А вы не думали что это может быть ленивая операция?

Comment: И вообще, неплохо бы понимать, что смысла в том, чтобы тянуть такой большой объём на клиента не нужно из практических соображений: либо считать на сервере, либо делать пагинацию и т.п.

Comment: Делаю Price структурой.
Добавляю значения так 
Prices.Add(new Price() { Timestamp = Convert.ToInt32(ConvertToUnixTimestamp(myReader.GetString(1))), Bid = Convert.ToDouble(myReader.GetString(2)), Ask = Convert.ToDouble(myReader.GetString(3)) });
Быстрее не становится. 
Проверял запрос при помощи HeidiSQL.
Найденные строки: 62 914  Предупреждения: 0  Длительность  1 запрос: 0,532 sec. (+ 0,328 sec. network)

Comment: То есть, 1 запрос? Чтение одной записи (RecordSet)? или Чтения всей виртуальной таблицы?

Comment: >>Проверял запрос при помощи HeidiSQL<< Так, а вы замерьте своим шарпом, может у вас именно в MySqlDataReader какие проблемы

Comment: А, ну и, обратите ещё раз внимание на комментарий @AK. Даже ваш HeidiSQL не способен за 1 секунду визуализировать 50к записей, скорее всего, вы просто что то не так объясняете...

Comment: Если я не присваиваю ничего в цикле while (myReader.Read()) {i++;} то все происходит очень быстро. Если беру из ридера DataTable и присваиваю своей какой-нибудь переменной то тоже все происходит быстро. Но как только пытаюсь циклом разбросать значения происходят тормоза.

Comment: БД локальная поэтому запрос выполняется очень быстро.

Comment: >>то все происходит очень быстро.<< >>А вы не думали что это может быть ленивая операция?<<

Comment: Вот вам попытка избавиться от ленивости: while (myReader.Read()) { myReader.GetString(0); i++; }

Comment: Замерил скорость первоначального варианта:
Время на запрос 0,641 сек., время на цикл 10,328 сек.
Варианта while (myReader.Read()) { myReader.GetString(0); i++; }
Время на запрос 0,625 сек., время на цикл 0,703 сек.
Это на 15000 строк,

Answer (score 0):

Докопался до причины. Оказалось все просто.
Виновата функция

```
static double ConvertToUnixTimestamp(string date_str)
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(date_str, new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
        DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        TimeSpan diff = date - origin;
        return Math.Floor(diff.TotalSeconds);
    }
```

Т.к. при конвертировании каждый раз создаются 2 объекта new CultureInfo("ru-RU") и new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) это порождает большое количество мусора.
В таком виде работает быстрее.

```
static CultureInfo Culture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
    static DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    public static double ConvertToUnixTimestamp(string date_str)
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(date_str, Culture);
        TimeSpan diff = date - origin;
        return Math.Floor(diff.TotalSeconds);
    }
```

Теперь на преобразование 60000 записей тратится 0,25 сек. вместо 30-40 сек.
Всем спасибо за участие.

Comment: В дотнете есть родные методы `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds` и `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds`, а также `ToUnixTimeMilliseconds` и `ToUnixTimeSeconds`.